# Export csv and force download in template page

Tags: page-template

I'm having trouble trying to build a page that let's someone download a .csv file containing data which is set in a variable from the frontend.

My code is below, but the only thing that is happening is that the data is being shown in the page, but there is no prompt to download the .csv file.

Can anyone see what the problem might be?

Thanks

Osu

```
<?php 
/**
 * CSV page template
 *
 */
?>

<?php get_header(); ?>

        <div id="sidebar-1">
            <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
        </div> <!-- End div#sidebar -->

        <div id="primarycontent">
            <?php get_template_part( '/loop', 'default' ); ?>

            <h2>Export</h2>

            <form action="" method="post">
                <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Export">
                <input type="hidden" name="submit" />
            </form>

            <?php
            // Check if form submitted before
            if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {

                $fileName = date("d-m-y") . '-bv-directory.csv';
                $content = ""; // content added below

                // Title of the CSV
                $content = "Name,Address,Age,Phone \n";

                // Data in the CSV
                $content .= "\"John Doe\",\"New York, USA\",15,65465464 \n";

                // Create csv and force download
                header('Content-Type: application/csv'); 
                header("Content-length: " . filesize($NewFile)); 
                header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $fileName . '"'); 
                echo $content;
            } ?>

        </div> <!-- End div#primarycontent -->

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put *all* the code that handles the output of the CSV before your `get_header()` call, then `exit`:

```
<?php 

/**
 * CSV page template
 *
 */

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {

    $fileName = date("d-m-y") . '-bv-directory.csv';
    $content = ""; // content added below

    // Title of the CSV
    $content = "Name,Address,Age,Phone \n";

    // Data in the CSV
    $content .= "\"John Doe\",\"New York, USA\",15,65465464 \n";

    // Create csv and force download
    header('Content-Type: application/csv'); 
    header("Content-length: " . filesize($NewFile)); 
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $fileName . '"'); 
    echo $content;

    exit;
}

?>

<?php get_header(); ?>

    <div id="sidebar-1">
        <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
    </div> <!-- End div#sidebar -->

    <div id="primarycontent">
        <?php get_template_part( '/loop', 'default' ); ?>

        <h2>Export</h2>

        <form action="" method="post">
            <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Export">
            <input type="hidden" name="submit" />
        </form>

    </div> <!-- End div#primarycontent -->

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: TheDeadMedic - You're fantastic, that totally worked. Thanks!